# Changing font family in memoir for page headers

Tags: xetex, memoir, titleps

I am using the memoir class with XeLaTeX and am using titleps to format my page headers. I need to change the font family only for the page headers because the main font I am using has no small caps. If I can use another similar font with a small caps option this would solve the problem.
I have checked the memoir class and titleps docs but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. Am I out of luck?

My (inadequate) solution is here:

```
\documentclass[legalpaper, twoside, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titleps}
\setmainfont{original font}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
% Try to change font family to a small caps font only for page header
\setmainfont{A different font}
\setheadrule{.2pt}% Header rule
\sethead[{\thepage} ]% even left
[\textsc{\footnotesize{\chaptertitle}}]% even center
[{\textsc{\footnotesize{Author \  Name}}}]% even center
[]% even right
{}% odd left
{{\textsc{\footnotesize{Title \  Of \ Book}}}}% o c
{{\thepage}}% odd right
% change font back to original font
\setmainfont{original font}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
A bunch of text goes here
\end{document}
```

This is clearly inadequate but I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: I tried your MWE but I got an error report about an undefined control sequence, via xelatex, of "\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}". I have just checked that my TeXlive is upto date. I don't know if it is my problem or your MWE. In any case I don't have the Book Antiqua or Minion Pro fonts so it's not easy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\newfontfamily` and avoid changing the main font mid document. Besides, it can't work the way you are trying to do.

You should also use the `memoir` specific functions for page styles.

For the example I used two fonts with very distinctive features, just to emphasize how and when they're used.

```
\documentclass[legalpaper, twoside, 11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily\headerfont{Libertinus Sans}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}
  {\headerfont\footnotesize\thepage}
  {\headerfont\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}
  {\headerfont\footnotesize\scshape Author Name}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}
  {}
  {\headerfont\footnotesize\scshape Title Of Book}
  {\headerfont\footnotesize\thepage}
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{.2pt}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter title}
\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]